# Does tcpdump supports 10 G data packets to capture?

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, packet-capture, nic, wireshark-dissector

I want 10G supported sniffer to capture packets.I searched many but i found that the common analyser wireshark doesnot support 10G packets.How to i sniff 10G packets .Is there any tool to sniff 10g data packets.

Any ideas or solutions will be appreciable

Comment: Wireshark doesn't care whether the interface is 1Gbps or 10Gbps, so it should support it. Please give more info about your 10G NIC information, the OS on the system etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does tcpdump supports 10 G data packets to capture?

The answer is: **Yes.**

Because:

`tcpdump`/ `wireshark` or rather the underlying `pcap` software does not care at all about `10baseT`,  `100baseT`, `1000baseT`, `one gazillion peta-bits-OMG-look-how-fast-I-go` per seconds or more.

*But* you will/may have issues on your CPU, RAM, disk access bandwidth. Because 10 giga-bits per seconds is a pretty heavy load no matter the software - this becomes a hardware issue.

Comment: Thankyou jbm.Now i am clear with that.can you suggest me.After i have captured large data.how can i parse and move it my database.Its very large right.i am expecting a response from you.